# Python: How to allow duplicates in a set?

Tags: python, set, duplicates

I ran into a problem regarding set in Python 2.7.

Here's the appropriate example code block:

```
letters = set(str(raw_input("Type letters: ")))
```

As you can see, the point is to write some letters to assign to "letters" for later use. But if I type "aaabbcdd", the output of "letters" returns

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

My question is how to write the code, so that the output will allow duplicates like this:

```
set(['a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d'])
```

?

Comment: A set is a data structure that only ever contains unique elements. If you want duplicates, use a different data structure (not a set).

Comment: for example `letters = list(raw_input("Type letters: "))` ?

Comment: -1: The question seems to disregard common mathematical definitions as well as the Python language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "set" with duplicate/repeated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176037/python-set-with-duplicate-repeated-elements)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`set` doesn't store duplicates, which is why it's called a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29). You should use an ordinary `str` or `list` and sort it if necessary.

```
>>> sorted(raw_input("Type letters: "))
Type letters: foobar
['a', 'b', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'r']
```

An alternative (but overkill for your example) is the multiset container [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), available from Python 2.7.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(raw_input("Type letters: "))
>>> c
Counter({'o': 2, 'a': 1, 'r': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> sorted(c.elements())
['a', 'b', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'r']
```

Answer (score 2):

A set does not allow duplicates by definition.
Use a simple list.

In your case:

```
letters = list(str(raw_input("Type letters: ")))
print sorted(letters)
```