# Python "set" with duplicate/repeated elements

Tags: python, collections, dictionary, set

Is there a standard way to represent a "set" that can contain duplicate elements.

As I understand it, a set has exactly one or zero of an element. I want functionality to have any number.

I am currently using a dictionary with elements as keys, and quantity as values, but this seems wrong for many reasons.

**Motivation:**
I believe there are many applications for such a collection. For example, a survey of favourite colours could be represented by:
    survey = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

Here, I do not care about the order, but I do about quantities. I want to do things like:

```
survey.add('blue')
# would give survey == ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue']
```

...and maybe even

```
survey.remove('blue')
# would give survey == ['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

**Notes:**
Yes, set is not the correct term for this kind of collection. Is there a more correct one?

A list of course would work, but the collection required is unordered. Not to mention that the method naming for sets seems to me to be more appropriate.

Comment: It might help by explaining why you want to do this.

Comment: If you need duplicates it's not a `set` by definition.  Can you demonstrate what you think you want, and maybe we can suggest an appropriate container or data type?

Comment: This is a contradictory request unless you clarify your intent. You could technically define a custom __hash__ method for your objects to allow duplicates in a set or dict but then it would be up to you to count them another way. I dont think you really want duplicate members if your goal is to count. Dict with count value doesnt seem wrong for many reasons.

Comment: If order is not important to you, the fact that list is ordered should not be a problem for you. Is there any reason you need to randomize the order?

Comment: If the OP rewords his question, it would be much better. It's enough to ask for a structure that "supports multiple identical elements"; asking for different method names and lack of order isn't reasonable. List isn't a good solution since it wastes memory when each element is repeated many times, and wastes time on insert/delete compared to multiset.

Comment: The beauty of stack overflow is that sometimes you don't know what you don't know. If I knew what I "should" have been asking, I may have been able to google it. The ability for a human to understand what is needed is why I eventually ask stack overflow after fruitless time spent googling. I hope this backlash towards undereducated people seeking help doesnt prevail over common decency. JSpolsky talked of the importance of the community here, and I can't help but feel something is going awry.

Comment: Under "Notes", I believe the term that the OP is looking for is `bag` (a common term for `multiset`)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are looking for a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Python's closest datatype is [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> A `Counter` is a `dict` subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be
>   any integer value including zero or negative counts. **The `Counter` class
>   is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.**

For an actual implementation of a multiset, use the [`bag`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/data-structures#id4) class from the data-structures package on pypi.  Note that this is for Python 3 only.  If you need Python 2, [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259174/) is a recipe for a `bag` written for Python 2.4.

Comment: What's the difference between collections.Counter and pypi's bag?

Comment: On python 2.7.6 I can run bag, why?

Comment: One big gotcha here: `len(counter_obj)` gives you the number of unique elements but not the total number of elements as you expect from a multiset. But, you can do all other operations like unions and intersections just as you do with sets.

Comment: @Phani:  Good point.  For total number of elements do `sum(counter_obj.values())`.

Answer (score 16):

Your approach with dict with element/count seems ok to me. You probably need some more functionality. Have a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

- O(1) test whether an element is present and current count retrieval (faster than with `element in list` and `list.count(element)`)
- `counter.elements()` looks like a list with all duplicates
- easy manipulation union/difference with other Counters

Answer (score 1):

> Python "set" with duplicate/repeated elements

This depends on how you define a set.  One may assume that to the OP

1. order does not matter (whether ordered or unordered)
2. replicates/repeated elements (a.k.a. *multiplicities*) are permitted

Given these assumptions, the options reduce to two abstract types: a [list](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/List.html) or a [multiset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiset.html).  In Python, these type usually translate to a `list` and `Counter` respectively.  See the Details on some subtleties to observe.

**Given**

```
import random

import collections as ct

random.seed(123)


elems = [random.randint(1, 11) for _ in range(10)]
elems
# [1, 5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 7, 9, 9]
```

**Code**

A list of replicate elements:

```
list(elems)
# [1, 5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 7, 9, 9]
```

A "multiset" of replicate elements:

```
ct.Counter(elems)
# Counter({1: 2, 5: 2, 2: 2, 7: 2, 9: 2})
```

---

**Details**

*On Data Structures*

We have a mix of terms here that easily get confused.  To clarify, here are some basic mathematical data structures compared to ones in Python.

```
Type        |Abbr|Order|Replicates|   Math*   |   Python    | Implementation
------------|----|-----|----------|-----------|-------------|----------------
Set         |Set |  n  |     n    | {2  3  1} |  {2, 3, 1}  | set(el)
Ordered Set |Oset|  y  |     n    | {1, 2, 3} |      -      | list(dict.fromkeys(el)
Multiset    |Mset|  n  |     y    | [2  1  2] |      -      | <see `mset` below>
List        |List|  y  |     y    | [1, 2, 2] |  [1, 2, 2]  | list(el)
```

From the table, one can deduce the definition of each type.  Example: a *set* is a container that ignores order and rejects replicate elements.  In contrast, a *list* is a container that preserves order and permits replicate elements.

Also from the table, we can see:

- Both an ordered set and a multiset are not explicitly implemented in Python
- "Order" is a contrary term to a random arrangement of elements, e.g. sorted or insertion order
- Sets and multisets are not strictly ordered.  They *can* be ordered, but order does not matter.
- Multisets permit replicates, thus they are not strict sets (the term "[set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Set.html)" is indeed [confusing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407209/why-is-it-called-a-multiset)).

*On Multisets*

Some may argue that `collections.Counter` is a multiset.  You are safe in many cases to treat it as such, but be aware that `Counter` is simply a dict (a mapping) of key-*multiplicity* pairs. It is a map of multiplicities.  See an example of elements in a flattened multiset:

```
mset = [x for k, v in ct.Counter(elems).items() for x in [k]*v]
mset
# [1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 7, 7, 9, 9]
```

Notice there is some residual ordering, which may be surprising if you expect disordered results.  However, disorder does not preclude order.  Thus while you can generate a multiset from a `Counter`, be aware of the following provisos on residual ordering in Python:

- replicates get grouped together in the mapping, introducing some degree of order
- in Python 3.6, dict's preserve insertion order

**Summary**

In Python, a multiset can be translated to a map of multiplicities, i.e. a `Counter`, which is not randomly unordered like a pure set. There can be some residual ordering, which in most cases is ok since order does not generally matter in multisets.

**See Also**

- [`collections-extended`](https://github.com/mlenzen/collections-extended) - a package on extra data types in `collections`
- N. Wildberger's [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyCRPT6iFBg&list=PLIljB45xT85AYIeGfDQwHM8i6PQEDnnTI&index=1) on mathematical data structures

<sup>*Mathematically, (according to [N. Wildberger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2beQrKjtzs&list=PLIljB45xT85AYIeGfDQwHM8i6PQEDnnTI&index=2), we express braces `{}` to imply a set and brackets `[]` to imply a list, as seen in Python.  Unlike Python, commas `,` to imply order.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain `list` and use `list.count(element)` whenever you want to access the "number" of elements.

```
my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]

my_list.count(1) # will return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative Python multiset implementation uses a sorted list data structure. There are a couple implementations on PyPI. One option is the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module which implements a [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) data type that efficiently implements set-like methods like `add`, `remove`, and `contains`. The sortedcontainers module is implemented in pure-Python, fast-as-C implementations (even faster), has 100% unit test coverage, and hours of stress testing.

Installation is easy from PyPI:

```
pip install sortedcontainers
```

If you can't `pip install` then simply pull the sortedlist.py file down from the [open-source repository](https://github.com/grantjenks/sorted_containers).

Use it as you would a set:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
survey = SortedList(['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green']]
survey.add('blue')
print survey.count('blue') # "3"
survey.remove('blue')
```

The sortedcontainers module also maintains a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) with other popular implementations.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is indeed a [*multiset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (or *bag*), a collection of not necessarily distinct elements (whereas a *set* does not contain duplicates).

There's an implementation for multisets here: https://github.com/mlenzen/collections-extended (Pypy's [collections extended](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collections-extended) module).

The data structure for multisets is called `bag`. A `bag` is a subclass of the `Set` class from `collections` module with an extra dictionary to keep track of the multiplicities of elements.

```
class _basebag(Set):
    """
    Base class for bag and frozenbag.   Is not mutable and not hashable, so there's
    no reason to use this instead of either bag or frozenbag.
    """
    # Basic object methods

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """Create a new basebag.

        If iterable isn't given, is None or is empty then the bag starts empty.
        Otherwise each element from iterable will be added to the bag
        however many times it appears.

        This runs in O(len(iterable))
        """
        self._dict = dict()
        self._size = 0
        if iterable:
            if isinstance(iterable, _basebag):
                for elem, count in iterable._dict.items():
                    self._inc(elem, count)
            else:
                for value in iterable:
                    self._inc(value)
```

A nice method for `bag` is `nlargest` (similar to `Counter` for lists), that returns the multiplicities of all elements blazingly fast since the number of occurrences of each element is kept up-to-date in the bag's dictionary:

```
>>> b=bag(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in xrange(10))
>>> b.nlargest()
[('p', 2), ('A', 1), ('d', 1), ('m', 1), ('J', 1), ('M', 1), ('l', 1), ('n', 1), ('W', 1)]
>>> Counter(b)
Counter({'p': 2, 'A': 1, 'd': 1, 'm': 1, 'J': 1, 'M': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'W': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used `collections.Counter` to implement a multiset, as already mentioned.

Another way to implement a multiset is by using `defaultdict`, which would work by counting occurrences, like `collections.Counter`.

Here's a snippet from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

> Setting the `default_factory` to `int` makes the `defaultdict` useful for counting (like a bag or multiset in other languages):
>
> ```
> >>> s = 'mississippi'
> >>> d = defaultdict(int)
> >>> for k in s:
> ...     d[k] += 1
> ...
> >>> d.items()
> [('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
> ```

Answer (score -2):

If you need duplicates, use a list, and transform it to a set when you need operate as a set.

Comment: It's most likely that the OP was looking for a multiset, and transforming a list to a set loses duplicates.

Comment: I posted this answer before it was edited. My approach is only use the set as a view of the original list.