# Is there a way to make a multiset?

Tags: python

Is there a way to create a multiset in python? I have my set here:
`{'a', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'e'}` but I would like to have repeated characters, but still unorganised. Thanks

Comment: Why necessarily unorganised? Do you mean `O(1)` checking of existence? Then dictionaries use key hashing and you can use value to store the count of items.

Comment: What problem you want to solve with multiset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python "set" with duplicate/repeated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176037/python-set-with-duplicate-repeated-elements)

Comment: Be careful that isn't an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in python since a set in python is by definition meant to be unique.

You can however install external packages to implement a multiset:

```
pip install multiset
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use:

```
from multiset import *
vowels_set = Multiset('auioe')
```

"A multiset is similar to the builtin set, but it **allows an element to occur multiple times**. It is an **unordered collection** of elements which have to be hashable just like in a set. It supports the same methods and operations as set does, e.g. membership test, union, intersection, and (symmetric) difference. Multisets can be used in combination with regular sets for those operations." - *https://multiset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/*

Answer (score 1):

The `multiset` library suggested here is fine - just to add a standard-library alternative, you can also use the `Counter` object from the `collections` library. You have to watch out as a `Counter` CAN have negative counts, which is not valid for a multiset; however there are set operations provided which will only ever produce positive counts and basically act like multisets. Counters return a count of zero for items not in the set, and let you check for set membership with the `in` operator, as you'd expect.

For anyone wondering about dictionaries vs lists vs sets...

A multiset is conceptually similar to a dictionary. That is, a multiset is equivalent to a dictionary whose keys are set items and values are counts of how many of that item are in the set. Using a simple dictionary is a bit awkward though - you have to make sure counts aren't allowed to drop to negative numbers, you have to check if a key is in the dictionary before you check its count, etc. And there are no set operations like union and intersection, or addition and subtraction.

A list can store multiple copies of an element, but removing an element from it involves searching through the whole list, which is inefficient. Convenient set operations also aren't available for lists (except addition).

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you want a list:

```
vowels = ['a','u','a','i','o','e']
```

A list can take repeated characters and is unordered. 
[This is the doc page for lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) if you want to find out more

Comment: Why is this downvoted, surely a list would meet the requirements?

Comment: What do you mean by "list is unorganised" ? (not downvoter).

Comment: But it is ordered.

Comment: You can have a list of integers not in order. [1,16,3].

Comment: That's not what unordered means. It means the collection as whole is unordered which is not true for lists. Once you define lists in one order, the order is intact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208062/discussion-between-eugeneprout-and-austin).

Comment: While a list is ordered by definition, it's true that you could use a list for this purpose and ignore the order. It just wouldn't be efficient, since to remove an item from the list, you have to search through potentially the entire list.