# How to determine if a list with duplicates is contained in another list also with duplicates

Tags: python, list

I want to compare 2 lists to know if one contains some elements of the other. Here's an example:

```
contents = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
expected = ['blue', 'blue', 'red']

if expected in contents:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I would like that code to return True.
But for example if I use:

```
expected = ['red', 'green', 'green']
```

That should return False 'cause there's only one green on the contents.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, even for duplicates:

```
def contains(haystack, needle):
    haystack = haystack.copy()
    for item in needle:
        if item not in haystack:
            return False
        haystack.remove(item)
    return True


contents = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
print(contains(contents, ['blue', 'blue', 'red']))
# True
print(contains(contents, ['red', 'green', 'green']))
# False
```

Comment: Will try it, but I'm trying to do it without importing any modules! Thanks anyway!

Comment: typing is not necessary here. You can remove it.

Comment: Nice then! I tried and it's working, thank you so much! And I'm actually trying to put this already in a function, is there any way to do it without the function? so I don't have to use a function inside of another function?

Comment: It's not working if i try to retrive more than 3 colours, any idea why?

Comment: Can you provide an example? `print(contains(contents, ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'green']))` works for me as well (= `True`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code piece.

```
contents = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
expected = ['blue', 'blue', 'red']
new_colours =[x for x in expected if x in contents] #=== Check if the value in contents
print(new_colours)
```

Output:

```
['blue', 'blue', 'red']
```

Here, I change `expected`list

```
expected=['blue','blue','yellow']
```

Output:

```
['blue', 'blue']
```

Comment: Okay, but that would create me a new list and it would be always True if there's at least one of the elements in there, I need something to check if all of them are in the other list and return True, but I think I'll take your idea and then count if the length of the output list is the same as the expected one, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem @PolPorta,

Comment: There's a still a problem with that, I could have 8 expected blue balls and it would return 8 times 'blue' while there are just 3!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `collections.Counter` here, (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176311/13386979)).  Get a count of the unique elements in `expected` and `contents`, then loop over the items in `expected` to make sure count in `contents` is at least as much.

```
from collections import Counter

contents = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
expected = ['blue', 'blue', 'red']

a = Counter(contents)
b = Counter(expected)

print(all([a[k] >= b[k] for k in b.keys()]))
# True

c = Counter(['red', 'green', 'green'])
print(all([a[k] >= c[k] for k in c.keys()])) # c instead of b
# False
```

Functional form:

```
def list_inside(contents, expected):
    contents = Counter(contents)
    expected = Counter(expected)
    return all([contents[k] >= expected[k] for k in expected.keys()])
```

Comment: Looks good but I would prefer to not import any module!

Comment: @PolPorta `collections` is part of the standard library, so it automatically comes with Python; I would say using these standard modules is encouraged if it helps your code!  I.e. don't re-implement things that are already available

Answer (score 0):

```
def colors():
    for x in expected:
        if x in contents:
            contents.remove(x)
            if x in contents:
                good.append(x)
    if len(good) == len(expected):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(colors())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.