# issubset() and difference() list equivalent

Tags: python

i need to use issubset() and difference() on lists but i can't translate my list in sets, because my list has duplicates and they are very important.
For exemple, i have

```
list1 = [33, 33, 100, 102,]
list2 = [33, 33, 33, 33]
list3 = [99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
list4 = [100,101,102,103,104]
```

i need to know that list1 is contained in list2 and that i need [33,33] in order for list1 to be equaled to list2 or that list1 is contained in list3 and list4

i have tried to do it with multiple 'for loops', but i can't seem to be able to get it right

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176037/python-set-with-duplicate-repeated-elements

Comment: Your question is a bit scattered. Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Those operations are properly defined for sets, you are going to have to describe the semantics as they would apply to lists and duplicates. Possibly, you want a multiset behavior, in which case, you could potentially use `collections.Counter`

Comment: In *what sense* is list1 is contained in list2, list3, and list4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, possibly, you are describing a multiset. So `collections.Counter` objects can serve as a multiset. Consider:

```
>>> list1 = [33, 33, 100, 102,]
>>> list2 = [33, 33, 33, 33]
>>> from collections import Counter
```

Then you can use:

```
>>> Counter(list2) - Counter(list1)
Counter({33: 2})
```

If you need a list, then:

```
>>> list((Counter(list2) - Counter(list1)).elements())
[33, 33]
```

But I suspect you should just be using `Counter` objects all along.

```
>>> c1 = Counter(list1)
>>> c2 = Counter(list2)
>>> diff = c2 - c1
>>> if diff == c2:
...     print("none of the elements of list1 are in list2")
... else:
...     print("some of the elements of list1 are in list2")
...     print("the missing elements are:", list(diff.elements()))
...
some of the elements of list1 are in list2
the missing elements are: [33, 33]
```

Comment: thak you for your answer, but what if you want something special to happen if c2 and c1 are the same? How do you write " if diff == Counter():" or "if diff == 0:" ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`. You can do many of the operations defined on sets using `Counter`, with intuitive outcomes (though for some of those you would need Python 3.10). For example:

```
list((Counter(list2) - Counter(list1)).elements())
# => [33, 33] (difference)

Counter(list2) <= Counter(list1)
# => False (list2 is not contained in list1)
```

If you don't have Python 3.10, the latter one won't work, so a workaround is needed. For example:

```
def issubcounter(smaller, bigger):
    return bool((bigger - smaller) and not (smaller - bigger))

issubcounter(Counter(list2), Counter(list1))
# => False (list2 is not contained in list1)
```

Answer (score -1):

When interpreting the elements of a list as set, we can use the definition that the list `a` is a subset of list `b` if all elements of `a` are contained in `b`. If you don't want to check this with an explicit `for` loop, create the list comprehension `[x for x in a if x not in b]` to find the elements that invalidate this property.

To account for duplicates (but not the order), I need a bit more and don't see an easy way to do this just with a comprehension.

```
def missing_in(sub, of):
    if not sub:
        return of
    if sub[0] not in of:
        return missing_in(sub[1:], of)
    ind =  of.index(sub[0])
    return missing_in(sub[1:], of[:ind]+of[ind+1:])
```

This finds the elements in `sub` that are missing in `of`: if sub is empty, every element is missing. If the first element of `sub` is completely missing in `of` we ignore it (if you want the symmetric difference, add it to the return list here). If it is present, the element is removed once from `sub` and `of` and we can continue with the next element of `sub`. A notion of sub(multi)set can be defined that `of` possibly contains some element missing in `sub` but not the other way around.

```
def proper_submultiset_of(sub, of):
    return len(missing_in(sub, of)) > 0 and not missing_in(of, sub)

def submultiset_of(sub, of):
    return not missing_in(of, sub)
```

I don't recognize a notion how `[33, 33, 100, 102,]` is contained in `[99, 100, 101, 102, 103]` though.

Comment: That *is a loop*

Comment: Should have written "With an explicit loop ", will fix.

Comment: but what about for the isdifferent function?

Comment: But it *still doesn't give you the correct answer*. Try it out with the example data

Comment: True, my solution doesn't care about duplicates (was interpreting the lists as sets where duplicates don't matter).

Comment: OP: "because my list has duplicates and they are very important"

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't write code late in the evening - I added a multiset version.