# Python: Does the set.add() function not add duplicates?

Tags: python, set

I have multiple tuples stored in a set, and I'm trying to add two duplicate tuples to the set through a nested for loop which basically iterates through another bunch of tuples and checks for a condition in the tuple, then adds the tuple to the set if the tuple meets the condition. However, some tuples are duplicate and I'm noticing the duplicates aren't being added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to allow duplicates in a set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455750/python-how-to-allow-duplicates-in-a-set)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) can not contain duplicates. That is the point of a set. If you want duplicates, consider using a list instead.

Answer (score 4):

Set by definition is unordered collections of unique elements, so they don't allow duplicates. Please check the python's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).